# Arranging books and stones (Counting)

Tags: combinatorics

You are given $6$ distinct books and $5$ identical blocks of woods. How many ways are there to arrange these books and woods in a straight line?

1. $11!/4!$
2. $11!/5!$
3. $11!/6!$
4. $11$ chooses $6$

I think the answer 4. because there are total of $11$ positions and I only need to consider how to arrange either $6$ books or $5$ woods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 11 objects of 7 types in all (6 different books, 5 blocks). This is a simple counting problem:
$$
\binom{11}{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5}
  = \frac{11!}{1! \, 1! \, 1! \, 1!\, 1! \, 1!\, 5!}
$$